# Put a line break before numeric character in string with php

Tags: php

I have strings like this:

```
123 qwerty 6 foo bar 55 bar
```

I need to make it like this

```
123 qwerty
6 foo bar
55 bar
```

How to make it?

**UPD:**
I tried make it

```
$subject = "123 qwerty 6 foo 55 bar";
$pattern = '/[^0-9]/';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
```

But it is no working for me.

Comment: What about `123 qwerty 6 foo 55 bar99x 1 abc`? Does bar99x get broken up or must the number occur after a space?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ], please.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I have a db, that already have the strings in this format.

Comment: no research work..nothing tried!

Comment: @JohnConde See upd, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this:

```
$text = '123 qwerty 6 foo 55 bar baz';
$result = preg_replace('/([0-9]+[^0-9]+)/i', '$1\n', $text);
```

This looks for at least one number followed by at least one character which is NOT a number and adds a linebreak.

Read more abot:

- [patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)
- [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
 $lineending= "\n";
 $parts= explode(' ',$string);
 $result= "";
 for($i=0; $i<count($parts);){
    $result .= $parts[$i];
    while(!is_numeric($parts[$i]) && $i<count($parts)){
        $result .= $parts[$i];
        $i+= 1;
    }
    $result .= $lineending; 
 }
```

;-)

Comment: Yes, your script works.
But maybe not the only one word per line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$subject = '123 qwerty 6 foo 55 bar';
$pattern = '/ (?=[\d]+)/';
$replacement = "\n";

$result = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $subject );

print_r( $result );
```

Produces:

```
123 qwerty
6 foo
55 bar
```

PHP Demo: http://codepad.org/MNLgaySd

---

The key is in the regular expression's "[positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)", `(?=...)`

Regex Demo: http://rubular.com/r/i4CdoEL9f4